# Can Elementary OS be made more like Mac?

Tags: macintosh

I have just installed Elementary OS (5.0) in a laptop which is otherwise booting to W10 and Linux Mint.

I've never been a Mac user but I was intrigued when people said EO was "very like Mac". And after installing it I find that it isn't really very much like Mac visually, compared for example to another Linux distro which I had a look at many years ago.

What about the nice little coloured buttons "minimise, maxmimise, close", or the kind of metallic look of dialogs? What about the way the icons in the bottom bar (or whatever you call it) sort of jump up and down when loading? Even the icons (for the various default installed apps on the bottom bar) look rather flat and boring. Nothing like the lovely shiny "bling", as we say in the UK, you get with Mac.

Is this maybe something to do with copyright? Would someone get sued if it looked more like Mac? Or is it actually difficult to do? I'm puzzled.

Does anyone know of any enhancements (skins, themes, or whatever these might be called) which give a better Mac look, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Just NO :p I mean this is linux, you can do anything, but then elementary will no logner be elementary. Also macOS is terrible OS, I have it at work now.

Answer (score 3):

I love elementary OS, and use it my self (and have) for a long time now. However, I would not recommend it for this endeavor. I'd go with something that is highly customizable (and meant to be customized) like Kubuntu, Xubuntu, etc.

Either way, there's a package called [MacBuntu](https://www.noobslab.com/2018/08/macbuntu-1804-transformation-pack-ready.html?m=1)
Which will give you a Mac OS X theme and icon theme.

And something called [elementary tweaks](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks)
Which will allow you to edit a lot of things regarding visual behaviour (including choosing the new theme and icon theme)

Id recommend trying using it as it is for a while though, it can take some getting used to, but it does have a really great design and incredible usability.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the top of my head, I can recommend [this short YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tK_bi_PFeY). It contains a lot of information on apps and themes you'd need to install and configure in order to get a mac-like look and feel (window controls position and colors, dock animations, icon colors...).

To that, I would also add the mac-like gestures for the touchpad by using the instructions in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma) (three-finger navigation and pinch to zoom).

There are a plethora of other resources on the topic online, and numerous prebuilt packages that will deliver the macOS experience, but, in my experience, they do tend to break the functionality and consistency of the OS. My advice would be to setup a virtual elementary OS machine using [Gnome Boxes](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Boxes), create a snapshot to be able to easily start from scratch, use that machine to experiment with different themes and apps, and when you're satisfied, replicate the setup on your laptop. If you get the time, feel free to publish here a list of the customizations you made, I believe there are some of us here looking for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

imo (you need elementery tweaks for this, install that, come back here) pretty easy you'll find all you need at gnome-looks, if you specifically want Mac, here's a [Big Sur GTK theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1405530/) theme which I personally use
to install that you'll have to go into the home folder, right click and view hidden folders, put the contents of the file you downloaded into .themes, if it doesn't exist, create it,
Second, you're gonna get the [icons](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1400021/), go to home, .icons, if isnt there create it, and then go to settings, tweaks and apply, you can also find the wallpaper [here](https://www.pling.com/p/1413279/), if you want to change cursors which I personally don't think is necessarily required, good luck guys.

Comment: Noah again here, sorry forgot to continue cursor bit, you gotta go here https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1408466/ , and put it also in the icons folder